# NoSuchMethodError - Intellij and lombok

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, lombok, junit5, intellij-lombok-plugin

I am getting a weird issue in IntelliJ.  I am using Lombok (1.18.2), IntelliJ(2018.2.2) and JUnit 5 in gradle 4 multi-module project.

It took me hours to replicate this.

1. Run all test case with coverage.
2. Following a pop up will come

[image]

3. if I press OK and re-run the unit test case. It will start failing with **java.lang.NoSuchMethodError** for the getters and setters.
4. removing Lombok and generating getter and setter after this has no effect as well.

Tried everything to fix this (enable annotation processor, Lombok plugin, clean build) but no luck.

**EDIT 1:**

**Root build.gradle:**

```
implementation 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.2'
testImplementation('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.3.1')
testImplementation('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:5.3.1')
testRuntime('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.3.1')
testImplementation("org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher:1.3.1")
testImplementation("org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine:5.3.1")
testImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-core:2.+"
testImplementation('org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:2.22.0')
```

**sub-project build.gradle**

```
compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
```

Comment: can you post the part of your `build.gradle` script where you configure  lombok dependencies ?

Comment: please see the edit.

Comment: could you try adding following dependencies : `testAnnotationProcessor "org.projectlombok:lombok:${lombokVersion}"` and `testCompileOnly "org.projectlombok:lombok:${lombokVersion}"` ? ( and clean/rebuild project)

Comment: No . It didn't solved the issue. gradle build is passing but the Intellij build is failing.

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? It's affecting me now. I managed to make it work by turning off "Delegate IDE build/run actions to gradle" in Gradle/Runner preference pane

Comment: Yes, I have solved this issue. Are you still struggling?

Comment: @MikeHoldsworth Please see the answer if you are still getting this issue. Sorry for the late reply.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved this issue by making following changes:

1. Enable annotation processing in Intellij.(File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Compiler | Annotation Processors)
2. select processor path and point to lombok-1.18.4.jar because I just want to enable it for Lombok and not for Mapstruct. If enabled for both then it generates the Mapstruct classes in default location.
3. under File "Invalidate cache and restart"
4. under Build option "Rebuild project"

This will solve it. It took me a while to make it working in Intellij.

Comment: This is a very good answer. it works